# Notepad++ hover preview on link or color?

Tags: plugins, hover, notepad++, preview

I was wondering if there is a option or **plugin**, which allows us **on hover to preview** either a **CSS color** or **image**, something like this:

[image]

And also if you **hover over an img src** - preview the img... ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try "Quick Color Picker for Notepad++". You double-click on the hex color and a color-picker pops up as well as a preview. Another cool thing is that it provides a few more colors that match the "theme" if you will.

**[Here is the link Quick Color Picker](https://github.com/nulled666/nppqcp)**

***SIDE NOTE:*** There used to be a feature or plugin, until very recently, that actually highlighted the text of the hex code with its color. It came out of nowhere after an N++ update and then it disappeared after another one. Can't figure out how to enable it again.

Comment: I found that other tool right after I posed this answer, haha. It's Notepad # ("sharp"). As I said, the hex code will be highlight in its color. You can go to the link below or download it directly from the Plugin Manager withing N++.

[Link to Notepad#](https://github.com/jvdanilo/NotepadSharp)

Comment: for clarity: (without any click) the _preview is the hex value underlined with the color_

Comment: @SeaBass the link is dead

Comment: First link works for me. Takes me to https://github.com/nulled666/nppqcp

Comment: Updated link for Notepad# https://github.com/Lomeli12/Notepad-Sharp

Comment: both plugins doesn't have the dll file so that they cannot be import to Notepad++. [How to install a Notepad++ plugin offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40015350/3416774)

Comment: @Ooker if I'm not mistaken, you should be able to compile your own from their code. If we're allowed to upload DLLs here I can give you my copy of NppQCP

Comment: I think it's fine. You can upload it to the plugin's repo too

Comment: Couldn't figure it out. Here's a dropbox link for the DDL. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/neta9iuzx7zpfzg/AABkwb5OWw4W_HqtCnFSYorXa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

[HTML color](http://npp.campulka.net/) is the closest thing I have seen when it comes to color preview. With it installed you select the color code and click a button to show the preview. From the preview you can change the color by a few clicks. It can also be used to insert new color codes.

Image preview I have never seen.