# How to install a Notepad++ plugin offline?

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I am trying to install a Notepad++ plugin from `Plugins -> Plugin Manager`, but my office firewall is restricting its download.
Is there any alternate way to install the plugin offline?

Answer (score 68):

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. [Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/) the plugin and extract the plugin dll file.
2. Place the plugin.dll file under plugin folder of notepad++ installation.
   For me it was : `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins`
3. Start Notepad++ as an elevated administrator and then go to: `Settings -> Import -> Import plugin(s)...` (import the plugin).
4. Notepad++ will show the restart message. / Sometimes it may not show it.
5. Restart the notepad++.
6. Should see new plugin under the Plugins menu. ALL DONE!!

Comment: This worked except I did not see the message about restart. But after restarting the plugin was installed. Also the download web is now: https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/

Comment: On Windows 10, you need to start Notepad++ as an **elevated administrator**, otherwise the the "import" step shown here will ***silently fail***.

Comment: @Glenn Slayden
This is an important step. Thanks. It would be helpful if this is added to this answer.

Comment: Plugin folder name must be the same as .dll file name

Comment: _> you need to start Notepad++ as an elevated administrator_.
– Not true. It doesn't _silently fail_.
But you have to restart _manually_ before you can start using the new
plugin.
(If elevated, then Notepad++ restarts automatically.
That's the only difference.)
~ * ~
For people coming here, I recommend also checking out
[this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451315).

Comment: @RV. please update the download link.  Here's the latest as of March-2024:
https://github.com/morbac/xmltools/releases/tag/3.1.1.13

Answer (score 20):

It's worth noting that the exact steps to follow can differ depending on the plugin. *(E.g. I've just manually installed XML Tools and this involved copying some files from a subfolder into the root Notepad++ installation directory.)* So would recommend the following:-

1. Download the plugin you wish to install. A comprehensive list is [the official Notepad++ Plugin List](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/nppPluginList/blob/master/README.md).
2. Extract to a local folder (e.g. using [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or similar).
3. Look in the extracted files and folders for any readme files or specific instructions to be followed - and then follow them. *In case there aren't any instructions, the one thing that must be done for all plugins is to copy the .DLL file into the plugins folder within your Notepad++ installation folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\`).*

Answer (score 10):

In version 7.7+, *Plugins --> Open Plugins Folder...*.
(This goes to `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins`.)

I had to **create a folder for the plugin and extract the .dll into the folder**.
*The folder must have the same name (case sensitive) as the `.dll`*.
For example, create a folder called `JSMinNPP` and place the `JSMinNPP.dll` in that folder.
(It doesn't work if the `.dll` is put directly in the plugins folder.)

*Settings --> Import --> Import plugin(s)...* and import the `.dll`.
Restart Notepad++.

Comment: It finally worked by following your advice, after having tried almost everything else. Great! The problem in this case is that Notepad++ doesn't report any error if you don't do what it expects. It just doesn't do anything. Very annoying.

Comment: Same for me, it MUST be in a separate folder under plugins path. Additionally in my case the folder also MUST have the same name (case sensitive) as the dll ex. in given example it should be ../plugins/JSMinNPP/JSMinNPP.dll. If i had put my plugin in ex. ../plugins/JsMin/JSMinNpp.dll it didn't work and no info/warning/error was given

Comment: As of v7.9, this was the first answer that actually worked for me. Apparently the key is that the folder name _must_ be the same as the DLL name... fortunately, you were trying to install JSTool as well. I tried the plug-in name (JSTool), the project name (JSToolNPP)... but nothing worked until I tried JSMinNPP. FWIW, it was _not_ necessary for me to use "Import plugin"... I just put the DLL in the folder of the same name and restarted the application. It took about a minute to start up, but when it did the plugin menu was (finally!) available :)

Comment: Excellent answer.
(It seems that _sometimes_ I don't need to import.
Just close & reopen _might_ be sufficient.)

Answer (score 9):

For me the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins` does not work.

I have to put plugins into the following directory:   `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Notepad++\plugins`

---

**UPDATE**

There is a feature from NPP-v7.6.4 to open plugin folder:

**`Plugins -> Open Plugins Folder...`**

Comment: since 7.6.1 plugins folder changed to : %PROGRAMDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\.

Comment: and the subfolder is needed. ie. %PROGRAMDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\AnalysePlugin\AnalysePlugin.dll

Answer (score 7):

My frustration in being unable to get a plugin for Notepad++ to work came from not realizing that the DLL for the plugin had to be installed directly in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins directory, and NOT into a subfolder below that, named for the plugin.

I was misled because every OTHER plugin that comes with the clean installation of Notepad++ IS installed in its own subfolder under \plugins.

```
\plugins
   ├ DSpellCheck
   ├ MIME Tools
   └ Converter (etc.)
```

I tried that with the plugin I was attempting to install (autosave), and just couldn't get it to work. But then thanks to an answer from Steve Chambers above, I tried putting the DLL directly into the \plugins folder and PRESTO! It Works.

Hope this helps save someone else similar frustrations!

Comment: that's odd, I had the exact opposite problem... I could only import/use the plugin if it was in its own self-named sub-folder.

Comment: @wrapperapps, it was the same for me (as for you). I'm guessing this may have changed over time.
If so, this answer is likely obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

Here are my steps tried with NPP 7.8.2:

(1)Download the plugins zip (refer plugin-full-list json):

https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/nppPluginList/blob/master/src/pl.x64.json

(2)Extract the files (normally .dll lib files) from zip to npp's plugins sub-folder

E.g.,  extract NppFTP-x64.zip into C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\NppFTP

Keep in mind:

```
  (i)Must create sub-folder for each plugin
 (ii)The sub-folder's name must be EXACTLY SAME as the main .dll filename (e.g., NppFTP.dll)
```

(3)Restart npp, those plugin will be automatically loaded.

[Note-1]: I didn't do setting->import->plugin, it seems this is not required
[Note-2]: You may need start npp with "run as administrator" option if you want to do import plugin.

Answer (score 3):

- Download and extract .zip file having all .dll plugin files under the path

  C:\ProgramData\Notepad++\plugins\
- Make sure to create a separated folder for each plugin
- Plugin (.dll) must be compatible with installed Notepad++ version (32 bit or 64 bit)

Comment: This is the right answer. You MUST create a separate folder for each plugin. This was the problem the whole time.

Answer (score 3):

If the plugin you want to install is not listed in the Plugins Admin, you may still install it manually. The plugin (in the DLL form) should be placed in the plugins subfolder of the Notepad++ Install Folder, under the subfolder with the same name of plugin binary name without file extension.

For example, if the plugin you want to install named myAwesomePlugin.dll, you should install it with the following path:

```
%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Notepad++\plugins\myAwesomePlugin\myAwesomePlugin.dll
```

or

```
%PROGRAMFILES%\Notepad++\plugins\myAwesomePlugin\myAwesomePlugin.dll
```

Once you installed the plugin, you can use (and you may configure) it via the menu “Plugins”.

Restart the Notepad++ after putting the plugin

Source : https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ address has changed, so many of the links above are broken. The up to date link for this question is here: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/plugins/

Just in case the address changes again, here is what we have there today:

**How to install a plugin**

**Install plugin manually**

If the plugin you want to install is not listed in the Plugins Admin, you may still install it manually. The plugin (in the DLL form) should be placed in the plugins subfolder of the Notepad++ Install Folder, under the subfolder with the same name of plugin binary name without file extension. For example, if the plugin you want to install named myAwesomePlugin.dll, you should install it with the following path: 
%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Notepad++\plugins\myAwesomePlugin\myAwesomePlugin.dll

Once you installed the plugin, you can use (and you may configure) it via the menu “Plugins”.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't import the .dll if it was already in the plugins folder. I put it in a temp folder on the C:\ drive, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

it'd be nice if it also looked for plugins in ~\AppData\local\Notepad++\plugins, for those of us working on locked down computers...

Answer (score 0):

Before using plugin **NOTE** plugins are usually in notepad 32 bit , 32 bit plugin is not compatible with 64 bit and vice versa(Recommendation use Notepad++ 32 bit) 
**Using Import in Notepad++** 
I tried Import plugin : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873143/3266623 
However it didnt worked for me 
**Manual way** 
1. Download and extract .zip file having all .dll plugin files under the path
C:\ProgramData\Notepad++\plugins\ 
To download use following link or google the same
http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Central 
2. For placing inside plugins - Make sure to create a separated folder for each plugin

```
\plugins
   ├ DSpellCheck
   ├ MIME Tools
   └ Converter (etc.)
```

3. (if plugin contains ext_libs folder) Copy ext_libs to the root notepad folder,Usually contains few ddl files i.e. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

For me the with NPP V7.6.6 (x64) this worked:

1. Download the plugin, and unzip to some local folder (e.g. Downloads).  Make sure you download the correct plugin for your Notepad++ (64 or 32 bit - e.g. see ? -> About Notepad++ to find if you are 64-bit)
2. Check each DLL to ensure it is unblocked (right-click, Properties, and check/select Unblock.
3. Run Notepad++. If you have UAC enabled, use "Run as Administrator" to run Notepad++ (Hold Shift key down, right-click Notepad++ icon, and select "Run as Administrator").
4. Go to menu Settings -> Import -> Import plugins...
5. Use dialog displayed to locate you local copy of the plugin DLL.
6. Once plugin DLL has been selected, Notepad++ should tell you you need to restart. If it doesn't, then Notepad++ has had some problem - though it doesn't tell you what...!
7. Restart Notepad++.

The above causes a copy of the plugin DLL to be copied under a subfolder of the same name in C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins.

Putting plugins directly into one of the following folders (or sub-folders for each plugin), as suggested in other answers, did not work for me:

a) %PROGRAMDATA%\Notepad++\plugins.
b) %ALLDATA%\Notepad++\plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Notepad++ as administrator, then import the .dll from the plugin folder that you pasted inside C:Program File/Notepad++/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is:

1. Put the plugin inside /plugin folder (for me it's XMLTools.dll, with some additional files that is instructed to be placed in the installdir)
2. "Run as administrator" on notepad++.exe
3. Settings>Import>Import plugin(s)..., browse to intended .dll, select it
4. Prompt comes up telling me to restart
5. Done!

Answer (score 0):

1. install a notepad++ at internet (online) side.
2. go to plugins ->  plugins admin -> choose and install the [needed] plugin.
3. copy the installed folder in C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins from online side to offline side.
4. restart notepad++